# how to manage Height of UITableHeaderView in based on webview content using auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, webview

When I add `UIWebView` on `headerview` using autolayout. I am not able to manage the height of `headerview` based on content of `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest these steps:

First, declare `webViewHeight` as class variable so it can be access by all functions.

```
var webViewHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
```

Then, get the height of the UIWebView content height. Make sure you have set the UIWebView delegate in `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    // check if webview finished loading
    if !webView.isLoading {
        if webViewHeight == 0 {
            // get webview height
            webViewHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        }

        // then reload tableView
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

It should update in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return webViewHeight
}
```

Comment: "webView.scrollView.contentSize.height"  it always return constant height.

Comment: @RajniJoharRaswant it should return double value. what did you get? try use print(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height) inside `webViewDidFinishLoad`

Comment: @RajniJoharRaswant great, dont forget to mark this answer. Thanks

Comment: I think this is not a better way because it's continues reload tableview when i did same. I don't know i am right or wrong please correct me.

Comment: @BhavsangJam great. So i think need to add condition to check if webview finish loading `if !webView.isLoading { // do the code here }`